# On building jenkins project timeout after 10 minute error happens

Tags: git, jenkins

I am using jenkins to build my git remote project. The problem is log says 'timeout after 10 min'. Receiving object starts and at 56% something happens.

Comment: Can you be more precise?
What is "something"?
Do other Jenkins jobs work successfully? If you don't have other Jenkins jobs you could add some just for testing.

Comment: Receiving objects:  56% (28596/50934), 942.31 MiB | 1.99 MiB/s   

 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1173)
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1043)
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$200(CliGitAPIImpl.java:74)
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:207)
 at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:621)
this was the error and it is my first project.

Answer (score 133):

Edit your job configuration, and under git plugin section:

- Click "Add"
- Click "Advanced clone behaviours"
- Set the number of minutes you want in "Timeout (in minutes) for clone and fetch operation"

I recommend checking also the "shallow clone" option. It fetches only the last state of the repository (without the history), so it's much faster.

[image: Image of configuration]

Comment: What is, if not clone and fetch is the problem, but push? I have the problem that git publisher aborts because git push takes longer than 10minutes because there is a hook executed on server site, which downloads a lot of packages and then build the web.... so where can I setup the timeout for push?

Comment: Thank you , was very helpful .
Capacity had been much time out too many .

Comment: @badera then it's not a jenkins issue, you should create a new question

Comment: @EdsonMedina: Agree, it is not an issue, but it is a setting of Jenkins when it should decide to abort the git push. I got it working and needed to change a settings in jenkins.xml

Comment: @badera do you mean config.xml? We've been looking for where to specify the push timeout. What attribute did you use? Thanks!

Comment: "Shallow clone" can substantially reduce the downloaded project's size, I recommend that before even changing the timeouts (which didn't want to work for me in fact).

Comment: This didn't work, at least when I use the git call in the pipeline itself.

Comment: This did not work for me, because it only applied to the 'git fetch' step, but the timeout was occurring in the 'git checkout' step.  It correct this, I added, "Additional checkout behaviors", and set the "Timeout (in minutes) for checkout operation" parameter.

Answer (score 12):

I have also face the same error while click on Build Now Button in Jenkins.

Why this error comes ?
Ans: This error was coming because of low Internet connection or may be the size of you project in github is large, so jenkins not able load/cone that project from git server.

Solution steps:

1. To resolve the problem we have to edit in Jenkins project configuration and find the `git`.
2. Then click on `Add` button and select `Advanced clone behaviors`.
3. `Timeout` (in minutes) for clone and fetch operations box put any number which is more then 10, (I put 60 here).
4. Apply and the save the configuration.
5. Build Now again , It took some more time to build , but it fixed the error.

Cheers :)

Comment: What is, if not clone and fetch is the problem, but push? I have the problem that git publisher aborts because git push takes longer than 10minutes because there is a hook executed on server site, which downloads a lot of packages and then build the web.... so where can I setup the timeout for push?

Answer (score 0):

As @edison-medina mentions, increasing the timeout may help but in my case the shallow clone was a better option. The shallow clone will dramatically reduce the time needed to clone a repo, specially one that has been growing for some time and may have hundreds or thousands of commits per file, because you'll only fetch the file version history indicated by the "depth" parameter on the `clone` command. For most CI use-cases, using "1" is the best option since only the latest version of a file is needed to complete a build.

To set this up in Jenkins, you'll need to open your project's configuration screen and find the section on Git, click the "Add" button under "Additional Behaviors", and select "Advanced clone behaviors". Check the "Shallow clone" option and set the depth to "1".

You'll need to do this for each project in Jenkins. I haven't seen a way to do this globally for all projects.