# Configure git timeout on Jenkins pipeline with Classic UI

Tags: git, jenkins, github, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I need to clone a plugin git public repository(that is not mine), zip it, and upload it to my server.

```
node {


stage('clone') { // for display purposes
    // Get some code from a GitHub repository
    git branch: 'master',
        url: 'https://github.com/LimeSurvey/LimeSurvey.git'
}
}
```

Thats my code, but the repository is heavy and gives me a 10min timeout error. I dont know if its a way to change the timeout time on the script.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [On building jenkins project timeout after 10 minute error happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22013217/on-building-jenkins-project-timeout-after-10-minute-error-happens)

Comment: Are you doing anything with the code? You could download the zip directly https://stackoverflow.com/q/2751227/1375964

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally could do it

Here's my code:

```
node {

stage('clone') { // for display purposes
    // Get some code from a GitHub repository
    checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
        branches: [[name: '*/master']],
        extensions: [[$class: 'CloneOption', timeout: 120]],
        gitTool: 'Default', 
        userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'https://github.com/LimeSurvey/LimeSurvey.git']]
    ])
}

stage('zip'){
    zip zipFile: './publish.zip',
        archive: true
}}
```